# Only display product that matches url id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to populate my product.html page using a html table and xml. My data is under var "productsXmlString". This cannot be changed. My problem is that my code places all products with not just the product with the same id as the url.

```
var productsDomTree = $.parseXML(productsXmlString);
var $products = $( productsDomTree );

var url = $(location).attr('href');
var urlid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

$products.find('product').each(function(){
var id = $(this).find('id').text();
var title = $(this).find('title').text();
var brand = $(this).find('brand').text();
var price = $(this).find('price').text();
var desc = $(this).find('description').text();

$('#mainTable > tbody').append("
<tr>
  <td>" + id + "</td>
  <td>" + title + "</td>
  <td>" + brand + "</td>
  <td>" + price + "</td>
  <td>" + desc + "</td>
</tr>
```

My data is too long to include in here but an example of it would be:

```
'<product top-level-category="Compact" sub-level-category="All-in-one"> <id>0019</id><title>NIKON COOLPIX</title><brand>Nikon</brand><price>200</price><description>example text</description>'
```

Any solutions would be massive help

Comment: couldn't you just wrap the append call in an `if (id == urlid) {...}`?

Comment: YES! thank you, that worked. Its been a long day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to ensure each product matches a certain criteria. The following code snippet highlights how to do this:

```
var id = /* read the id from the url */;

var $filtered = $products.find('product').filter((i, el) => {
  // Only return true if id matches the value in the url
  return $(el).find('id').text() === id;
});
```